# How to capture whatever is between an integer and its successor

Tags: regex, perl

How can I capture whatever content is between an integer and its successor? For example, suppose we are to capture `b3c`, which is between `1` and `2` in `a1b3c2d`. The code below gives us `b3c2d`.

```
'a1b3c2d' =~ / (\d+) (.+) (?{ $1 + 1 }) /x;

print $2, "\n";
```

Comment: what is `whatever`? whitespace, other integers, ...?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does your string come from? (i.e. what does it represent?)

Comment: integers are numeric list item markers, while letters are list items text.

Comment: So you're trying to parse a representation of a list? Is that a custom format you're using or is it a commonly-used format like XML/HTML/TeX, etc.?

Comment: I know you know, but it will break if the item text contains the next item marker `a1b2c2d`, you should change the format, not the parsing

Comment: You should include that in your question. You're likely to get better answers that way because if people can see a more representative example of your data, they can take edge cases into consideration better. For example, I imagine input like `1. foo 2 bar. 2. foo 2005 bar.` isn't out of the question, but it would cause hobbs's current solution to choke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *two* question marks in that construct. With just one it just puts the value of the code into `$^R` and returns a match

```
'a1b3c2d' =~ / (\d+) (.+) (??{ $1 + 1 }) /x;

print $2, "\n";
```

#### output

```
b3c
```

Comment: Note that this matches `34d5`, `3d45`,  `39d4`, `3d94` and `3d9d4`. Don't know if they're acceptable or not.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `(??{ ... })`, which interprets the result of the code block as a regex, and not `(?{ ... })` which always succeeds as an assertion. And you probably want to use a non-greedy quantifier in between so that it stops at the *first* match of the following number. Put together, `/ (\d+) (.+?) (??{ $1 + 1 }) /x` does the job.

You might also want to add negative assertions before and after the code assertion, to prevent matching an "incomplete" integer — i.e. you wouldn't want to treat the first digit of "21" as being "2". That would give

```
/ (\d+) (.+?) (?<!\d) (??{ $1 + 1 }) (?!\d) /x
```

altogether.

Comment: That looks very little different from my solution, except for some speculation about what the OP may want. I think it would be much more useful to prevent the second number from being found as part of a longer digit string

Comment: You also need to check the beginning, as in `a1b3c12`!

Comment: Erm, `(?!\d)` before the second number will never match. Should I write this for you?

Comment: @Borodin noted, and fixed (I believe).

Comment: Instead of lookbehind, maybe look for `(.*?)` followed by non-digit followed by `(??{ ... })`

Comment: I still think all of this is irrelevant to the question

Comment: There is such a thing as actually being helpful, and not just answering the exact words of a question. It's worked out for me so far. If what I've said doesn't help anyone, then I made a bad guess, but it's not *harmful*. I always put the most grounded stuff first and my interpretation later on, so that if someone just wants a literal answer they don't have to wade through a pile of crap to get it. :)

Comment: I agree, but when there is such very limited information in the question it is pointless to speculate. From the OP's comments it looks like `\b (??{ $1 + 1 })  \.` would be most appropriate

Comment: Note that this matches `34d5`, `39d4` and `3d9d4`. Don't know if they're acceptable or not.